# admin not opening after installing extension Magento2

Tags: magento2.2.0

This is what I am getting:

> {"0":"Specified invalid parent id
>   (Magewares_MWParent::parent)","1":"#0
>   /home/oesinter/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder->getResult(Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Menu))\n#1
>   /home/oesinter/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callParent('getResult',
>   Array)\n#2......

Can anyone guide me how to solve it.

Comment: please share  Magewares/MWParent/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml file

Comment: i changes syste.xml file with <tab>mwquickview</tab> with section id.
Now no error found but this extension is not displaying anywhere at backend.DO u still need menu.xml

Comment: if possible then share system.xml

Comment: system.xml  file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HI_Yycem1N2PwBYyJsikEQD6VrqljjM5

Comment: I ran into this error as well. The issue for me was that this module requires a parent module that was not included (Magewares_MWParent). This parent module is referenced in the menu.xml along with ACL rules. This basically broke the admin completely.